# Flux V2 is unable to clone a repo

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-deployment, flux

I'm trying to use flux v2 for continuous deployments on my K8 cluster. But when I try to create my flux source is gives the following error

```
✚ generating GitRepository source
► applying GitRepository source
✔ GitRepository source created
◎ waiting for GitRepository source reconciliation
✗ unable to clone: remote authentication required but no callback set
```

I'm trying to connect my azure repo here and I have obtained a PAT from azure and has applied it here

Can anyone please help me out?

**UPDATE**

I have managed to get it running with SSH keys from Azure

Comment: could you please expand on your solution?

Comment: @Bastian I have added the complete answer below. I did a bit more digging after I thought I resolved it.

Comment: ho thank you so much @lp-nave I'm still stuck with this issue. I understand the error could come from various underlying problems.

Comment: @Bastian true, could be. I checked this on my on prem servers and in an ec2 instance. The flux in the ec2 had no trouble of this kind. Once you set it up it works as it should. Its only my on prem servers that I kept facing this issue.

Also please check the authentications provided from the repos end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual issue was that the internet drop occasionally in the environment. what happens then is the pods in the flux namespace lose connection to your image repository. Then what you must do is restart the pods in the flux namespace. Then you can execute the reconcile commands on the image automation controller and the source controller..

```
flux reconcile source git <source name you have used when configuring>

flux reconcile image update <image update automation name you used>
```